# Azure web application - view slowest requests?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Web App and the monitor page in the Azure portal shows the average response time for requests. Is there any way to see which requests are the slowest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be Application Insights. It's free up to 7 days of data.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

Usually, for each Web App you create it automatically creates the app insights account. Check new portal.